# Does C# have access to the same stuff as GDscript?

Tags: c#, godot, gdscript

I barely scratched the surface of using godot, but I prefer the syntax of `C#` a lot more than `gdscript` (I hate _s in my code). I was wondering, does C# have access to all the same methods that `gdscript` comes with? Or would I have to import libraries and stuff from other people / write my own version of these methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe functionally, there is no big difference, most of the difference is of syntactic due to the different styles (of C# and python)

Refer to this link for more details.

> https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/getting_started/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_differences.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it when I can :)